# How i can make accuracy SpeechSynthesisUtterance lips on GIF

Tags: javascript

i have this project when speech is on pause like if there . or , or ? the Utterance take some millisecond and continue to talk, I want if their punctuation mark to display silent gif and if their talking to display lips movement gif and otherwise display hiddle gif so the lip movement will look like someone talking but problem is not accuracy when speech on going the silent display i want to be accuracy please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text to Speech</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .container {
            margin: 50px auto;
            width: 80%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        textarea {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        button {
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #lipGif,
        #lipSilent,
        #iddle {
            width: 34%;
            height: 23%;
            display: none;
            /* Hide initially */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
        <textarea id="textToSpeak" rows="4" placeholder="Enter text to speak..."></textarea>
        <button id="speakButton">Speak</button>
    </div>
    <img id="lipGif" src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEg-_Tvyma0BGv056krKRI7c_LCjZyjzb68vMprSOqSziEK7Ut4a7QWU8qRit3qNau7gaHt_KMl9v1n4wGXvr6DxvnsWQeiLgLqieN_ghFIF6kDfmJvU2SRI6Kz_F_W1C3hDhuupiI0QwkPyHkwYm_9m7mO9ex9OLDb2z2aLgkD1GgaJf21MgelHpgZUN8I/s320/dux4.gif" alt="Lips animation">
    <img id="lipSilent" src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEivGwlopz4dCieqlQmrcbKP12KTTSb2_Pkji1zfhdRfE5afcKoQ5mC_tlMEoKq61qhoEolvJr-4b11fwZq0kAg3habVrfcKErtrEDSphWDNxedUZzaNPtDAYQ0ui_VEJ5Fsts5Gs9320EUDBTQ8VHTEec6AQKCDDkKU-w5Ooh1OItdOQABrlfVwbsj2sKA/s320/duxsilent.gif" alt="silent animation">
    <img id="iddle" src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEjaME89fsOuRgrQsSRJTucinXsMCK26aA6_4PCtC0a0K3_nqvpwwKr_mI1NsMFEHSINgjY-divbArLYciXTacdUs-yD9csMsFjFGwkznNvHdtBUKHdt-ckykYV0tRp9572Wi2_JyKwbQii5pyZPuOiAVnJYzUjmbq3YSlrFmj_KKlIc0ilRdE1GUtqcT4I/s320/Dux_Male_Iddle.gif" alt="Hiddle animation">
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const textToSpeakInput = document.getElementById('textToSpeak');
            const speakButton = document.getElementById('speakButton');
            const lipGif = document.getElementById('lipGif');
            const lipSilent = document.getElementById('lipSilent');

            const iddle = document.getElementById('iddle');


            speakButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const text = textToSpeakInput.value.trim();
                if (text !== '') {
                    speakText(text);
                } else {
                    alert('Please enter some text to speak.');
                }
            });

            function speakText(text) {
                const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
                let lastCharIndex = 0;
                let silentTime = 200; // Time in milliseconds for silent image display

                utterance.onboundary = function(event) {
                    if (event.name === 'sentence' || event.name === 'start') {
                        const textChunk = text.substring(lastCharIndex, event.charIndex + 1).trim();
                        lastCharIndex = event.charIndex + 1;
                        if (textChunk.endsWith('.') || textChunk.endsWith(',') || textChunk.endsWith('!') || textChunk.endsWith('?')) {

                        } else {

                            setTimeout(showSilentAnimation, 10); // Show silent animation with a delay after speech ends

                            setTimeout(hideSilentAnimation, silentTime);
                            console.log("no");
                        }
                    }
                };




                utterance.onstart = function() {
                    showLipAnimation(); // Show lip animation when speech starts
                };

                // Ensure silent animation is hidden when speech ends
                // Ensure silent animation is hidden when speech ends
                utterance.onend = function() {
                    hideLipAnimation();
                    hideSilentAnimation();
                    lipGif.style.display = 'none';
                    lipSilent.style.display = 'none';
                    iddle.style.display = 'inline';
                };



                speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
            }

            function showLipAnimation() {
                lipGif.style.display = 'inline';
                console.log("talking");
                lipSilent.style.display = 'none';
                iddle.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function hideLipAnimation() {
                lipGif.style.display = 'none';
                lipSilent.style.display = 'block';
                iddle.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function showSilentAnimation() {
                lipSilent.style.display = 'inline';
                lipGif.style.display = 'none';
                iddle.style.display = 'none';
            }

            function hideSilentAnimation() {
                lipSilent.style.display = 'none';
                lipGif.style.display = 'inline';
                iddle.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which browser you are on and which speech synthesis engine is being used.

On Chrome user text is sent to remote Google servers when Google voices are used.

On Chromium browsers the local Speech Dispatcher installation is used.

AFAICT `onboundary` doesn't work at all.

You can break your input down into parts and create your own parser and output therefrom, e.g., here's my implementation of SSML parsing, which Web Speech API talks about, yet nobody has gotten around to implementing in the browser https://github.com/guest271314/SSMLParser.

Comment: thanks for, im not familiar with this library(https://github.com/guest271314/SSMLParser.) can you help me , i tried to create project when i enter text to textbox and click button the voice to speak but i'm getting error

Comment: What error are you getting?